# This is taking an unexpectedly long time

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

When I am trying to add new dependency (packages) using `flutter pub get` in my flutter project i am getting `This is taking an unexpectedly long time` message. 
All other commends working fine like `flutter run, flutter doctor` etc. Only for `flutter pub get` i am facing this issue. That's why i am unable to add new dependency (packages) in my flutter app.

Result of `flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.0, on Linux, locale en_IN)
    • Flutter version 1.17.0 at /home/suhask/private_work/Flutter/SDK/flutter_linux_1.17.0-stable/flutter
    • Framework revision e6b34c2b5c (9 days ago), 2020-05-02 11:39:18 -0700
    • Engine revision 540786dd51
    • Dart version 2.8.1


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/suhask/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /home/suhask/install_soft/android-studio-ide-183.5522156-linux/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b16-5323222)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at /home/suhask/install_soft/android-studio-ide-183.5522156-linux/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 39.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b16-5323222)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

If anyone know how to solve this problem please help.

Comment: so did `flutter pub get` finish with an error? your packages are not installed? `"This is taking an unexpectedly long time"` is an informational message

Comment: Not finishing with error and also package is not installed

Comment: are there any dart processes running while showing "This is taking an unexpectedly long time"? if so, be patient and let it finish..

Comment: No dart processes are not running.

Comment: last night i updated flutter 1.17. After updation i am facing this issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213597/discussion-between-nagesh-and-pskink).

Comment: I used to encounter the same problem, use `flutter pub get --verbose` to get more info, maybe you can get some error message.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on **Windows OS**,

1. Close Android Studio
2. End process related to Flutter & Android Studio IDE from Task Manager.
3. Then, delete everything from `Temp` folder **(run `%temp%` to open it directly)**.
4. Now, Open Android Studio and your Flutter project.
5. Run `flutter pub get`, it will work now.

Answer (score 1):

Use `flutter pub get --verbose` to get more info.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,  i did the next

uninstall the android studio, i installed the 4.0.1 version

[image]

Also I deleted the flutter sdk and download again in the page official

[flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows)

Finally i executed the command 'flutter doctor'

> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.2, on Microsoft Windows [VersiÃ³n
> 10.0.18363.1016], locale es-ES)
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 29.0.3) [!] Android Studio (version 4.0)
> X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
> X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality. [!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3)
> X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
> X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality. [!] VS Code (version 1.48.1)
> X Flutter extension not installed; install from
> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
> [!] Connected device
> ! No devices available
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 4 categories.

it permits to create a success project